# Concerning the product of all unique positive divisors

Tags: integers

> If the product of all the unique positive divisors of $n$, a positive integer which is not a perfect cube, is $n^2$, then the product of all the unique positive divisors of $n^2$ is:
>   (A)    $n^3$
>   (B)    $n^4$
>   (C)    $n^6$
>   (D)    $n^8$
>   (E)    $n^9$

I tried using the formula: $\frac{n^{d(n)}}{2}$, where $d(n)$ is the number of factors and I got the answer as $n^7/2$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 1):

Since the product of positive divisors of $n$ is $n^{\frac{d(n)}{2}}$. We want 
$$n^{\frac{d(n)}{2}}=n^2.$$
This means $d(n)=4$. So either $n=p^3$ or $n=pq$. The first possibility is ruled out since $n$ is not a cube. Thus $n=pq$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Then $d(n^2)=(2+1)(2+1)=9$ and the product of divisors of $n^2$ is 
$$(n^2)^{\frac{d(n^2)}{2}}=(n^2)^{9/2}=n^9$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** First, note that for the above condition to hold, $n$ cannot be prime and hence can be considered as the product of two primes, $p$ and $q$.

Then, try to list out the factors of $n^2= p^2q^2$.

Comment: Hello, @j.doe, you can accept the answer by ticking the question mark on the side if it helped you.